# Getting insight into partitions of a table in Azure Synapse (similar to SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I'm using [Dedicated SQL-Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-what-is) AKA Azure Synapse (which is different from serverless/on-demand Synapse that comes with Azure Synapse Analytics). And [According to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition):

> While the syntax of partitioning may be slightly different from SQL Server, the basic concepts are the same.

- I have a table that receives ~33 million new rows per day.
- Column named `version` indicates the day on which that row arrived. E.g. all 33 million rows arriving on `2021-05-22` have same `version` value (`2021-05-22`).
- Currently it has ~300 million rows (9 days worth of data).
- Table has daily partitions.

Here is the order of things I did:

- create table with 345 daily partitions (from 22-May-2021 to 30-Apr-2022).
- insert 9 days (33 million x 9 = ~300 million rows) worth of data into this table. I used `INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM some_other_table_with_300_million_rows`)
- update statistics mytable

**Question**

- Expectation: I have 9 partitions with ~33 million rows and 336 partitions with 0 rows.
- Reality: All partitions have equal amount of data.

When I run [this SQL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT 
    partition_id, index_id, partition_number, rows, data_compression_desc 
FROM 
    sys.partitions 
WHERE 
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')
```

I get this result:

```
partition_id        index_id    partition_number    rows    data_compression_desc
72057597508452352   1           1                   868784  COLUMNSTORE
72057597508583424   1           2                   868784  COLUMNSTORE
......
72057597553410048   1           344                 868784  COLUMNSTORE
72057597553541120   1           345                 868812  COLUMNSTORE
```

868784 * 345 = ~300 million

[This SQL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) however:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_partition_stats 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')
```

returns no rows.

Comment: Hard to say based on information you've provided. Try to create a simper repro, perhaps with just a few partitions and post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question may get closed - you didn't clearly ask a question, but I think this is what you are after.

The "object_id" in your query is expecting a id value of the table, not the table name. [I misread it originally, and I assume that is what the OBJECT_ID function is for. Still, there is no guarantee this table has entries for the table you are referring to]. I would instead join to sys.tables and sys.schemas to get the value:

```
SELECT TOP(100) s.name AS [SCHEMA_NAME], t.name AS TABLE_NAME, st.*
FROM sys.tables t
        join sys.schemas s
            on s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
        join sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_partition_stats st
            on st.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE s.name = '{yourschema}'
AND t.name = '{yourtable}'
```

For what it's worth, I've found the sys tables referencing Partitions to be extremely unreliable. I have Partitioned tables with lots of skew, but the system queries show them all with the exact same number of rows even though the distributions are NOT ROUND_ROBIN. Honestly, I just ignore this data. As long as you are using the partitioned columns in your WHERE clause, you should get the benefit regardless.

Comment: I was one of the two folks who voted to close, after I discovered dba community. I was just hoping someone else will also come along and vote to move it so I don't have to close it here and post a new one over there.

Comment: I tested with query you posted as well, same result (0 rows). `OBJECT_ID()` does work and provides the `object_id` of table. I checked by doing `print(OBJECT_ID('mytable'))` and the same thing does work when querying `sys.partitions`

Comment: I have some partitioned tables that return results and some that don't, so I'm not surprised (although I don't understand it).